# my rowfilter for regexstring is wrong

Tags: hbase

I want to get all rows end with `2017-04-12`. Shell command is `scan 'tr_log_v2', {FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:*2017-04-12')"}`. And an error happens `Incorrect filter string RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:*2017-04-12')`. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What is `2017-04-12`? Row key value? Column value? Post some sample scan result.

Comment: `2017-04-12` is part of my row key, `5188052635782977382:5946345666846493714:2017-04-12`

Comment: @franklinsijo That works, thanks so much. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this comparator `'regexstring:2017-04-12$'`

The scan statement would be,

```
scan 'tr_log_v2', {FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:2017-04-12$')"}
```